# Como dividir o valor de um elemento de uma coluna por delimitador (p.e "|") no pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Imaginemos que temos a seguinte coluna:

```
coluna1
ola | 52
   hey
   sou
   ja
 da |5
  24g
```

O output esperado seria:

```
coluna1
   ola
    52
    hey
    sou
     ja
     da
     5
     24g
```

Até ao momento, estou a tentar a manipulação de string com o split e rsplit e ainda não consegui obter o resultado esperado...como p.e

```
 df.coluna1.str.split("|")
```

Update:

```
coluna1
ola | 52 | 55 |23
   hey - e| 10 |12
   sou
   ja
  da |5 |ola
   24g
```

Output esperado:

```
coluna1
   ola
    52
    55
    23
    hey - e
    10
    12
    sou
     ja
     da
     5
     ola
     24g
```

Neste caso só da divide do primeiro | que aparece ... nos outros não!

Comment: tudo resolvido com o primeiro método!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de se fazer isso é utilizando a função `explode` do próprio `Pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['coluna1'].str.split('|').explode().reset_index(drop = True))
```

Entrada:

```
    coluna1
0   ola|52
1   hey
2   sou
3   ja
4   da|5
5   24g
```

Saída:

```
    coluna1
0   ola
1   52
2   hey
3   sou
4   ja
5   da
6   5
7   24g
```

Descrição:

> Transforme cada elemento de uma lista em uma linha, replicando os
> valores do índice.

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df['coluna1'].str.split('|').explode().reset_index(drop = True))
```

Nova entrada:

```
coluna1
ola | 52 | 55 |23
   hey - e| 10 |12
   sou
   ja
  da |5 |ola
   24g
```

Saída:

```
coluna1
0   ola
1   52
2   55
3   23
4   hey - e
5   10
6   12
7   sou
8   ja
9   da
10  5
11  ola
12  24g
```

Comment: obrigado @Imonferrari...mas e se tiver vários | ? Já não funciona...

Comment: Zoramind, boa tarde! Em que caso não funciona?

Comment: vou editar que se calhar é mais fácil de explicar! Obrigado!

Comment: Mas a Solução que te passei funciona pra este novo caso....

Comment: Veja o update, é o mesmo código, agora atribui o comando a variável `df`

Comment: Muito Obrigada! estava a repetir e não valia a pena...Perfeito!

Comment: Por nada! Que bom que resolveu. Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Opa,

Vc pode fazer conforme abaixo:

### Criando o DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"coluna1": ["ola|52", "hey", "sou", "ja", "da|5", "24g"]})

>>> df

>>> df
  coluna1
0  ola|52
1     hey
2     sou
3      ja
4    da|5
5     24g
```

### Fazendo o "split"

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.Series(row['coluna1'].split('|')) for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()

   index    0
0      0  ola
1      1   52
2      0  hey
3      0  sou
4      0   ja
5      0   da
6      1    5
7      0  24g
```

Perceba que a coluna `index` mostra qual era a posição do string.

Espero ter ajudado.